# Error "This API project is not authorized to use this API" - while trying to get lat,lng base on address

Tags: google-maps, curl, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoding-api

## I have

```
$url = https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=111+Park+AveFloor+4New+York%2CNY%2C10022%2CUSA&key=***
```

## I tried

making a curl get to get my lat,lng

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 1000);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    // dd($info);

    curl_close($ch);
    $result =  json_decode($result, true);
    return $result;
```

---

## Google Developer Console

[image]

---

It looks like I enable everything more than I should, but when my curl response kept showing

## CURL Result

```
array:3 [▼
  "error_message" => "This API project is not authorized to use this API. Please ensure that this API is activated in the APIs Console: Learn more: https://code.google.com/apis/console"
  "results" => []
  "status" => "REQUEST_DENIED"
]
```

---

## Curious ... ?

What did I forgot/do wrong ?

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));

what json are you sending to google maps api, exactly? because it looks like you're saying "here is a json request!" but you send an empty request

Comment: Unfortunately, after removing it, I still face the same problem.

Comment: btw what happens if you take out the key entirely from the url?

Comment: Wo hoo !!! It works !!

Comment: So that API doesn't require the key ?

Comment: for small number of requests, no. but you'll probably need the key if you will make such requests frequently from the same IP :/ i think there's something wrong with your api key configs, but i dont know what

Comment: I'll just create a new key tmr. Thanks for helping me on this. :)

Comment: im just guessing here, maybe you must "apply for a quota" for Maps Coordinate API

Comment: apply for quota , I don't know what that is yet, but I will look into it tmr. :)

Comment: What **kind** of key are you using? Server or browser?

Comment: Oh O. I'm not sure. I have to double check on that. I'm glad you brought that up.